# How do i fix the wrong integration of an automatic transfer of rows between sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

- have a data input sheet called 'data' (its data is fed by a form)
- script moves the information from data to sheet1/sheet2/.../sheetn (according to a string that is to be found in column 3)
- script also deletes moved rows

I think the deleteRow command works fine, i suspect the culprit being the detection of the string in the array.

I've already used the search a lot, tried a few codes and I've identified this as the most probable candidate (its by cooper), as it's almost doing what i need it to do.

I tried logging a bit, but unfortunately i dont know too much about coding yet. Currently im learning by trial and error. 
If i log for vals[i][2] i only get 1 string, instead of a few from my example input.

When i set only one targetsheet (sh1) and target-term it works. but when i extend it it doesnt work anymore.

```
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Applesheet');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Banana');
  var sh3=ss.getSheetByName('Cherry');

  var vals=rg0.getValues();
  Logger.log(vals)  
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>0;i--)
  {
    if(vals[i][2]=='Apple')
     Logger.log("PV Abfrage -", vals[i][2])
    {
      sh1.appendRow(vals[i]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
   if(vals[i][2]=='Banana') //also tried with else if here
    {
    sh2.appendRow(vals[i]);
    sh0.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
   if(vals[i][2]=='Cherry')
    {
    sh3.appendRow(vals[i]);
    sh0.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

My code moves rows that dont contain any of the terms.
It's also supposed to only move rows that contain this term, but its doing so super unrealiably. 
I think all rows get appended to Applesheet, rows that contain banana are moved to banana but the ones with cherry wont.
Im *definitely* not experienced enough to judge, but this code seems a bit unreliable, because even my test version with just one if fails to perform the way i want it to.

Comment: Remove the `Logger.log` in the middle of where you're trying to start your first `if` statement, it's forcing it to return `true` no matter what the value in the array is.

Comment: Oh wow, that seems to do the trick. thanks a lot. have a nice day!

Comment: @ross can you put your comment as an answer please?

Comment: @AndresDuarte I was just in the middle of writing one with examples, posted now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

Your first `if` statement is forced to return `true` by the `Logger.log()` you've included between `if` and `{`. As soon as you remove it, your code functions exactly as you're expecting.

---

#### Example:

If we run the following script:

```js
var check = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Fruit'];
for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
  if (check[i] === 'Apple') {
    console.log('Found!');
  }
}
```

We're looping through an array, and logging "Found!" for every time the item in the array is found. This is the same way your script works. It works as expected, "Apple" is only found once in the array, so the log looks like this:

> Found!

---

As soon as we put a log between the `if` and the `{`, like so:

```js
var check = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Fruit'];
for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
  if (check[i] === 'Apple') 
  console.log("Oops!") 
  {
    console.log('Found!');
  }
}
```

We get the following:

> Oops!
>   Found!
>   Found!
>   Found!

---

#### Summary:

Make sure to *only* include your conditions for the `if` statement between your `if` and `{`, adding anything else can return false positives like you've experienced today.

---

#### Reference:

- [JavaScript `if` Statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: This is quite interesting--do you know what the root cause of this? I initially guessed that Javascript was 'skipping over' the `(...)` and seeing the `Logger.log()` return truthy, but checking it out, putting falsy values **also** executes the if-statement. It also throws an error on encountering `else`, but otherwise runs fine.

Comment: For others, I think I answered my own question: It appears to be caused by [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/) ; e.g., it is not being parsed as `if (cond) ??? { statement-block }`, but as `if (cond); expression; { expression-inside-a-block }`. This is why `else` throws an error--as far as the parser is concerned, there was no preceding if-statement.